# Переименование фото, сделанного с камеры и его сохранение. Android java

Tags: java, android, камера

Мне нужно чтобы фотографии, полученные с камеры, переименовывались и сохранялись по пути: `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/`

Подскажите что не так в коде. Приложение вылетает после завершения активности камеры.

Вот код:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button buttonCheck = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mainButton);
        buttonCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                String imagesFolder = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/"; 
                File image = new File(imagesFolder, "face_1.jpg"); 
                Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1112);
            }
        });
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode == 1112){
        Bitmap face = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Output.class);
        intent.putExtra("face", face);
        startActivity(intent);
    } }
}
```

Comment: В документации написано, что при указании параметра `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` в `onActivityResult` не передается битмап с картинкой низкого разрешения, так что возможно вы там где-то получаете `NullPointerException`. Попробуйте вместо `Bitmap face = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); ` проверять, что появился файл.

Comment: zRrr, то есть `if(file.exists(){}` ?

Comment: да видимо, вы ж его все равно потом переименовывать собрались. Кстати, зачем переименовывать, если вы можете сразу указать нужное имя файла?

Comment: Переименовывать мне нужно каждое полученное фото на face_1, face_2, face_3 и т. д. Может как-то это сделать с помощью массива?

Comment: Так вы же сами это имя файла создаете и передаете. Заведите счетчик, увеличивайте на единицу при каждом использовании камеры.

Comment: Счетчик сбрасывается при рестарте приложения

Answer (score 1):

Пробуйте вместо

```
String imagesFolder = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/"; 
File image = new File(imagesFolder, "face_1.jpg");
```

вот так

```
File imagesFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
imagesFolder.mkdirs(); 
File image = new File(imagesFolder, "face_1.jpg");
```

и права в манифесте

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но как бы сделать чтобы приложение не вылетало?

Comment: @Никитоs, добавьте в вопрос логи, так не понятно